# XML File decryption with tripdes algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, tripledes

we have some of encrypted xml files which contain below kind of characters Like:
$¹QÆ¨Jiå•Á@Ü¶Äºµé)‰ï¦MSš¨íÄ;GfóûÇsHte;2Ð_.
can anyone guide us about how to decrypt such file content using TripleDes algo in C#.

Comment: How are you encrypting it? You need to use the same Initialization Vector (IV), key and key size

Comment: We got already encrypted Files, we have a key for that but no info about what IV,key size.

Comment: @MindSwipe I am using below settings:
tdes.IV = new byte[tdes.BlockSize / 8];
tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

Answer (score 0):

Have already use DES encryption and not Triple DES, hope this help

As a reminder DES is a symmetric encryption that's mean a single key is used both to encrypt and decrypt data. 
Below how to use DES Encryption and Decryption

Create resource file and name it CryptoKeys

Add the below string to CryptoKeys file

```
DesVector:0x11, 0x45, 0x47, 0x61, 0x12, 0xbc, 0xad 0xfc:;
DesKey:0xff, 0x12, 0x63, 0xa, 0x16 0xcf, 0xaf, 0xfb;
```

Create static class to manage the encryption and Decryption

```
public static class CryptoHelper
{
    //Init the key and Vector
    public static void InitDESKeys()
    {
        try
        {
        MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream();
        string[] charkey = Resources.CryptoKeys.DesKey.Split(',');
        string[] chariv = Resources.CryptoKeys.DesVector.Split(',');
        MemoryStream MemoryStreamkey = new MemoryStream(DesKey);
        MemoryStream MemoryStreamiv = new MemoryStream(DesVector);

        foreach (string item in charkey)
        {
            MemoryStreamkey.WriteByte(Convert.ToByte(item, 16));
        }

        foreach (string item in chariv)
        {
            MemoryStreamiv.WriteByte(Convert.ToByte(item, 16));
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    //Create function DESEncrypt to manage the encryption

    public static string DESEncrypt(string sourceData)
    {
        try
        {
        byte[] sourceDataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(sourceData);
        MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream();
        DESCryptoServiceProvider encryptor = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        CryptoStream encryptionStream = new CryptoStream(tempStream, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(DesKey, DesVector), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        encryptionStream.Write(sourceDataBytes, 0, sourceDataBytes.Length);
        encryptionStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        byte[] encryptedDataBytes = tempStream.GetBuffer();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedDataBytes, 0, (int)tempStream.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        throw new Exception("Unable to encrypt data.");
        }
    }

    //Create function DESDecrypt to manage the decryption

    public static string DESDecrypt(string sourceData)
    {
        try
        {
        byte[] encryptedDataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sourceData);
        MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedDataBytes, 0, encryptedDataBytes.Length);
        DESCryptoServiceProvider decryptor = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        CryptoStream decryptionStream = new CryptoStream(tempStream, decryptor.CreateDecryptor(DesKey, DesVector), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        byte[] bytesCryptedData = new byte[tempStream.Length];
        decryptionStream.Read(bytesCryptedData, 0, (int)tempStream.Length);

        var CryptedDataText = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytesCryptedData);
        return CryptedDataText;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        throw new Exception("Unable to encrypt data.");
        }
    }
}
```

Call the Encryption in the Main Class

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   CryptoHelper.InitDESKeys();
   string strText==Strin.Empty();
   strText="Text to decrypt";
   string encryptedText=CryptoHelper.DESEncrypt(strText);
   string decryptedText=Strin.Empty();
   decryptedText=CryptoHelper.DESDecrypt(strText);
}
```